# Henri Cartan's Proof of Existence and Uniqueness of Haar Measure

Tags: reference-request, haar-measure

Could someone please direct me to a reference for the above proof (the one that does not use the axiom of choice)?

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's always Cartan's original paper

> Cartan, Henri (1940), "Sur la mesure de Haar", Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences de Paris, 211: 759–762

which you can find online at http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/4197_ca400001.pdf.  I don't know of a modern or English exposition of Cartan's original argument per se, but Alfsen gave a simplified version of Cartan's argument with a full exposition:

> Alfsen, E.M. (1963), "A simplified constructive proof of existence and uniqueness of Haar measure", Math. Scand., 12: 106–116

which you can find online at http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10675/8696.

Comment: Another danish reference : (http://www.math.ku.dk/~jakobsen/gramps/haarintegral.pdf)